# Trouble writing data in a csv file

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've written a script in `node` using `puppeteer` to fetch  different `names` and the `links` to their profiles from a webpage. The script is fetching them in the right way.

What I wish to do now is write the data in a csv file but can't find any idea how to do so. I have come across many tuts which describe about writing the same but most of them are either incomplete or using such libraries which are no longer being maintained.

This is what I've written so far:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const link = "https://www.ak-brandenburg.de/bauherren/architekten_architektinnen";

(async ()=> {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const [page] = await browser.pages()
  await page.goto(link)

  const listItem = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.views-table tr')].map(item => ({
      name: item.querySelector('.views-field-title a').innerText.trim(),
      profilelink: "https://www.ak-brandenburg.de" + item.querySelector('.views-field-title a').getAttribute("href"),
    }))
  );
  console.log(listItem);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

***How can I write the data in a csv file?***

Answer (score 2):

There is a far easier way to achieve the same. If you check out [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv), you can write the data in a csv file very easily.

Working script:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Json2csv = require('json2csv').Parser;
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const link = "https://www.ak-brandenburg.de/bauherren/architekten_architektinnen";

(async ()=> {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const [page] = await browser.pages()
  await page.goto(link)

  const listItem = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.views-table tbody tr')].map(item => ({
      name: item.querySelector('.views-field-title a').innerText.trim(),
      profilelink: "https://www.ak-brandenburg.de" + item.querySelector('.views-field-title a').getAttribute("href"),
    }))
  );
  const j2csv = new Json2csv(['name','profilelink']);
  const csv = j2csv.parse(listItem);
  fs.writeFileSync('./output.csv',csv,'utf-8')

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with puppeteer but I have created csv file in my node project

Store your data in a array eg: csvData

Then use fs.writeFile to save your csv data.

```
`fs.writeFile(`path/to/csv/${csvName}.csv`, csvData, 'utf8', function(err) {
 if (err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  }
  res.send({
    url: `path/to/csv/${csvName}.csv`
  })
})`
```

> only use res.send if you want to send csv file from server to client